# Difference between getElementById and jquery $('#smth')

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

What's the difference between classic Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('theID')
```

and the jQuery version:

```
$('#theID')
```

Comment: I love that regular JS is called "classic".

Comment: @Spanky i think there needs to be a new tag started on SO "classic-javascript" due to the amount of questions asked that clearly state "no jQuery" or they dont even reference jQuery ever and people still just post jQuery snippets haha

Comment: We demand to see the error :D

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns a DOM object. This is the browser's native way of thinking about an element in the page.  It has various methods and properties.  These can be a little clunky to use.

The jQuery object (created by the `$` method) is a wrapper around a DOM element or a set of DOM elements.  The normal properties and methods are not available; you get a selection of different methods that make the process of DOM manipulation more intuitive.

The difference is more clear to see with multiple elements in the selection (as you would get with a class selector `$('.someClass')` for instance, but the methods on a jQuery selection are different to the ones on a native DOM element.  They point to the same thing, but they are different ways of thinking about it and dealing with it.

---

As a final note, you can convert a jQuery selection into its native DOM element(s) with the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method (edit: or the alternative array-like syntax).  So

```
document.getElementById('theID')
```

is exactly the same as

```
$('#theID').get(0) // or $('#theId')[0]
```

Note, however, that you should use the first, as it has much better performance.  Only use jQuery if you need the extra functionality it provides.

Comment: Why `.get(0)` instead of `[0]` ?

Comment: @Raynos Explicitness... I've added the alternative notation.

Comment: Thanks for your help that's the answer i would expected to listen.. :)

Comment: How can make the same object returned by $ by using getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Well in your second project, you might not have included the jQuery files at the the top.

Comment: No the jQuery was linked correctly, the error was old but the code i used is document.getElementById('viewport').scrollTop

When i change the getElement didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

In your `<head>`

If you don't load `jQuery` then you cannot use `$` as jQuery is an external library and not part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite : 
If an element with that id is not existing on the page
$("#id") will not work and the script will stop
document.getElementById("id") will return null