# How can I remove an element in Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript

Im trying to remove a Div from the DOM via an `<a>` tag nested within it.

I guess what I am looking for is the pure Javascript version of jQuery's 
    `$('div').remove()`
Here's the html set up

`<div> <a href = "#" onClick = "w/e()">Click me to remove the parent div</a></div>`

Thanks ahead of time. :D

Comment: See comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103766/diference-between-getelementbyid-and-jquery-smth

Comment: @spanky: So? That is not a reason. Only because people don't understand that jQuery is just a library or that `javascript` questions should not be answered with jQuery, does not justify such a tag. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: If that's what you think, that's your opinion. I didn't create the tag, so obviously other people think it's helpful as well.

Comment: @spanky: Currently I see only you using that tag. If people think it is necessary they will add it themselves. Otherwise it is also only *your* opinion that the questions should be tagged like this. But we can discuss this on meta...

Comment: @Felix - he gets reputation points for every post he adds a link to. Why wouldn't he want to add tags?

Comment: IMHO - Javascript should be javascript(classic, pure, w/e) jquery should be $() stuff. I learned Jquery before I learned javascript. Sad isnt it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could define this function

```
function remove(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

and use it as

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onClick="remove(this.parentNode)">...</a>
</div>
```

**Reference:** [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode), [`Node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild)

**Further notes:**

- You better use a `<button>` instead of a link (`<a>`) for this kind of behaviour. A link has a distinct semantic meaning, it has to link *somewhere*. You can use CSS to style the button accordingly.
- Event handlers are better added via JavaScript itself and not as an HTML attribute.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to add a button's listener using script in this case since if script isn't supported, the button isn't going to work anway. In the OP's case it may be better to use a link with a listener - if javascript is available, do the action and cancel navigation. If it isn't available, the link should cause the same action to occur, just that a new page will (probably) be involved.