# Parse HTML without IDs or classes

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use Javascript to parse html without IDs or classes?

For example I want to delete everything from "Starting date" to "Starting time"

```
<div class="timer">
  <!--Starting date-->
  <select>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
  </select>
  <!--Starting time-->
  <select>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
  </select>
  <!--more select tags here>
</div>
```

Comment: which parts of the text would you like to remove?

Comment: With Jquery you can do this easily, just hide the entire div, that is, if the class or its id is unique: `$('.timer').attr('hidden', true)`

Comment: @MartinMeli 'For example I want to delete everything from "Starting date" to "Starting time".'

Comment: @SillasSenna I don't want to remove the entire div. Only part of it!

Comment: You either work with `innerHTML` and string functions here (_find_ the position of the parts you want to cut, remove them, assign result to the div again), or on the DOM level, remove individual nodes and text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work after making the nodelist static

```js
let hideDate = true; // your condition
const startText = "Starting date",
  endText = "Starting time";
if (hideDate) {
  let i = 0;
  const nodes = [...document.querySelector(".timer").childNodes]; // make list static
  for (; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3 &&
      nodes[i].textContent.trim() === startText) break;
  }
  for (; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3 &&
      nodes[i].textContent.trim() === endText) break;
    nodes[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  Starting date
  <select>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
  </select>
  Starting time
  <select>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `let i=0; for (;i<nodes.length;i++) { if (…) break; } for (;i<nodes.length;i++) { if (…) break; nodes[i].remove(); }` instead of an extra `removeStart` variable, and instead of never checking for staying within `nodes.length` in the second loop

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this:

you have to select this element from javaScript for example:

```
var elementsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName/TagNames('element class or element tag name');
```

this will return you a list of elements, so you need to get one of them, like this:

```
elementsContainer = elementsContainer[0]
```

this will give you one element, so after this, you can delete its content like this

```
elementsContainer.innerHTML/innerText = '';
```

you can choose one of this property innerHTML or innerText according to which you need

Answer (score 0):

Well for your problem. I would suggest to have a look at the concepts of `jquery remove()`, and `jquery empty()`. here are some working test demos of these two methods.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".timer select").remove();
});
</script>
```

The above code will completely remove the elements inside the div element. see here [Jquery Remove Wroking Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_remove)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".timer").empty();
});
</script>
```

This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements
[Jquery Empty Working Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_empty)

Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it.

If you want to do it with core javascript then have a look at it.
[Jquery Remove method using core JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104154/12525976)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let timer = document.querySelector('.timer')

const from = 'Starting date'
const to = 'Starting time'

let html = timer.innerHTML
timer.innerHTML = html.slice(0, html.search(from)) + html.slice(html.search(to))
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  Starting date
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  Starting time
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Because I changed substring to slice

Comment: That would have been visible, if you had left the snippet. It is really nice to have a snippet to run

Comment: But your code does not do what OP wants. See my answer. Your original WOULD work if you just removed the to.length