# Content page button click event not triggering from master page using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and content page, In content page I have a button with server side click event.
I want to call the content page button server side click event from master page button onClientClick event using JavaScript/jQuery. See below code which I tried, It is not showing any error (I have verified errors using F12 browser developer tools) and not firing the event. See below my code and suggest if I missed anything.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           console.log("ready!");           
           $("#btnMasterSubmit").click(function () {
               var btnContent = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave');
               btnContent.click();
           });
       });
   </script>
```

***The same code is working in IE browser but not in Edge and other browsers. I want to work this in Edge browser only.***

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: change `document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave');` to `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave");` There is a different between these two. Navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103766/difference-between-getelementbyid-and-jquery-smth for more info

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb thanks for your reply, even using $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave"); also not triggered server side click event.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in the master page like so

```js
$(document).on('click', "#btnMasterSubmit,#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave", function(e) {
  clickHandler(e);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  let id = $(e.target).attr('id');
  if (id == "#btnMasterSubmit") {
    // do something
  } else if (id == "#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave") {
    // do something else
  }
}
```